# jQuery: Create and submit a form with file upload

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a simple  field somewhere in my document. 
Now I want to CREATE a form with jQuery, add this input field to it and submit it via Javascript.

Something like this:

```
var newform = $( document.createElement('form') );
newform.attr("method","post")
       .attr("action",action)
       .attr("enctype","multipart/form-data");
       .append($("#file").clone())
       .submit();
```

Unfortunately, $_FILES gives me error code 4: "No file submitted".
I tried this with simple Text fields, and it worked for them, their value has been submitted too. Just the file-upload won't work.

Any suggestions how that could be done?

Comment: AFAIK file is contained in $_FILES, not in $_POST

Comment: of course, how stupid. :( Anyways, I'm getting error code 4, "no file was submitted"

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the fact that `$("#file").clone()` would cause the input appended to the form to have the same id `'#file'`.